# Elevation Shadow Not Changing Based on Height

Tags: java, android, shadow, elevation

If I have two items side-by-side with elevation set to 100, neither shows a shadow along the adjoining side. However, if I set one to elevation 99, a shadow appears. This is good. What is not good is that no matter what the elevation I set it to --- 99, 50, 5 --- the spread and opacity of the shadow stays exactly the same. How can I get the elevation to be sensitive to the height difference rather than just *whether* a difference exists?

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure how the shadow is drawn by the framework. My theory is that the side by side elevation is caused by the elevation of 100 (since it's above the other one that you set to 99 or 50 or 5). If you change one of the elevation to 500 and leave the other one as is, do you see the same shadow?

Comment: The shadow spreads out more in that case, but it seems odd since how much a shadow can spread in real life depends on how close the object it falls on is. If that is close, it's sharper and less diffuse, if further, it's more spread out. This seems to work the opposite and behave according to the number of what's causing the shadow rather than the difference of what it's falling on.